Find the minimum of $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{x^n+y^n}+\frac{1}{x^n+z^n}+\frac{1}{z^n+y^n}}$ when $x+y+z=1,x,y,z\geq 0,n\in\mathbb{N}^*$
Find the minimum of $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{x^n+y^n}+\frac{1}{x^n+z^n}+\frac{1}{z^n+y^n}}$ when $x+y+z=1,x,y,z\geq 0,n\in\mathbb{N}^*$.
I can only handle the cases when $n=1$ or $n=2$, but I fail to have a more generalized result. When $n=1$, using the CS-inequality, we have $$\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{1}{x+z}+\frac{1}{z+y}&=\frac{(x+y)+(y+z)+(x+z)}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{1}{x+z}+\frac{1}{z+y}\bigg)\\&\geq\frac{(1+1+1)^2}{2}=\frac{9}{2}\end{aligned}$$
However, when $n=2$, things become a little bit complicated. The minimum is $10$, and the following is my proof. First, let $$\begin{aligned}S&=\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}x\\P&=xyz\\Q&=\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}xy\end{aligned}$$
Now we have $$\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}(x^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)}{(x^2+y^2)(z^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)}$$ and $$\begin{aligned}\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}(x^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)&=S^4-4QS^2+5Q^2-2PS\\(x^2+y^2)(z^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)&=S^2Q^2-2PS^3-2Q^3+4PQS-P^2\end{aligned}$$
Since $S=1$, we have $$\frac{\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}(x^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)}{(x^2+y^2)(z^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)}=\frac{1-4Q+5Q^2-2P}{Q^2-2P-2Q^3+4PQ-P^2}$$
Then $$\begin{aligned}\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}-10&\geq 0\\ \Leftrightarrow 10P^2+(18-40Q)P+(5Q^2-1)(4Q-1)&\geq 0\end{aligned}$$
Since $\displaystyle Q=\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}xy\leq \frac{(x+y+z)^2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$, we know that $18-40Q\geq 0$.
To prove $10P^2+(18-40Q)P+(5Q^2-1)(4Q-1)\geq 0$, there're two cases.
(i) $\displaystyle Q\leq \frac{1}{4}$. In this case $(5Q^2-1)(4Q-1)\geq 0$, and therefore $$10P^2+(18-40Q)P+(5Q^2-1)(4Q-1)\geq 0$$
(ii) $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}<Q\leq \frac{1}{3}$. In this case, by the Schur's inequality, $$\begin{aligned}&\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}x(x-y)(x-z)\geq 0\\\Leftrightarrow &S^3-4SQ+9P\geq 0\\\Leftrightarrow &P\geq\frac{4Q-1}{9}\end{aligned}$$
Then in order to prove $10P^2+(18-40Q)P+(5Q^2-1)(4Q-1)\geq 0$, we need only to prove $$10\bigg(\frac{4Q-1}{9}\bigg)^2+(18-40Q)\bigg(\frac{4Q-1}{9}\bigg)+(5Q^2-1)(4Q-1)\geq 0,$$
which is equivalent to $$\bigg(Q-\frac{1}{4}\bigg)(1620Q^2-1280Q+284)\geq 0$$
Note that $1620Q^2-1280Q+284$ is always positive, then we're done.
However, when $n\geq 3$, I fail to get further. Plz help me if you have a nice solution for tackling the cases when $n\geq 3$. If possible, plz do not use caculus including derivatives. But if caculus is necessary, just use it.

I know you don't want to use calculus, but I would try Lagrange multipliers.

I'm a bit fuzzy on the details of your proof, but it seems to me that you have: WLOG $ x \leq y \leq z$ then $ f(x, y, z) \leq f(0, 1-z, z ) \leq f( 0, 0.5, 0.5)$ hence we are done.

I think if $n\ge 2$, the minimum is $5\cdot 2^{n-1}$ when $x = y = 1/2, z = 0$.

Can you give a proof @RiverLi? By the way, I think I've successfully handled the case when n=2 and I've updated a proof in the post.

@grj040803 For $n=2$, your solution is the so-called pqr method. Usually, $p = x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz$.

Remark. We deal with the case $n\ge 4$.
Fact 1. Let $n \ge 4$ be a real number. Then the minimum of $\frac{1}{x^n + y^n} + \frac{1}{y^n + z^n}
+ \frac{1}{z^n + x^n}$ is $5\cdot 2^{n-1}$ when $x = y = 1/2, z = 0$.
Proof of Fact 1.
WLOG, assume that $x \ge y \ge z$.
Using OP's AM-GM idea, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{1}{x^n + y^n} + \frac{1}{y^n + z^n}
 + \frac{1}{z^n + x^n}\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{1}{x^n + y^n} + 4 \times \frac14\left(\frac{1}{y^n + z^n}
 + \frac{1}{z^n + x^n}\right)\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 5\sqrt[5]{\frac{1}{x^n + y^n} \cdot \frac{1}{4^4}\left(\frac{1}{y^n + z^n}
 + \frac{1}{z^n + x^n}\right)^4}\\
 ={}& 5\sqrt[5]{\frac{1}{x^n + y^n} \cdot \frac{1}{4^4}\left(\frac{x^n + y^n + 2z^n}{x^ny^n + z^n(x^n + y^n) + z^{2n}}\right)^4}\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 5\sqrt[5]{\frac{1}{x^n + y^n} \cdot \frac{1}{4^4}\left(\frac{x^n + y^n}{x^ny^n + z^n(x^n + y^n) + z^{2n}}\right)^4}\\[6pt]
 ={}& 5\sqrt[5]{ \frac{1}{4^4}\left(\frac{x^n + y^n}{x^ny^n + z^n(x^n + y^n) + z^{2n}}\right)^3 \frac{1}{x^ny^n + z^n(x^n + y^n) + z^{2n}}}\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 5\sqrt[5]{ \frac{1}{4^4}\left(\frac{x^n + y^n}{\sqrt{x^ny^n}\,\frac{x^n + y^n}{2} + z^n(x^n + y^n) + z^n\,\frac{x^n + y^n}{2}}\right)^3\frac{1}{x^ny^n + z^n(1-z)^n + z^{2n}}} \tag{1}\\[6pt]
 ={}& 5\sqrt[5]{ \frac{1}{4^4}\frac{8}{(\sqrt{x^ny^n} + 3z^n)^3}\cdot \frac{1}{x^ny^n + z^n(1 - z)^n + z^{2n}}}\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 5\sqrt[5]{ \frac{1}{4^4}\frac{8}{[(x+y)^n/2^n + 3z^n]^3}\cdot \frac{1}{(x+y)^{2n}/2^{2n} + z^n(1 - z)^n + z^{2n}}}\tag{2}\\[6pt]
 ={}& 5\sqrt[5]{ \frac{1}{4^4}\frac{8}{[(1 - z)^n/2^n + 3z^n]^3}\cdot \frac{1}{(1-z)^{2n}/2^{2n} + z^n(1-z)^n + z^{2n}}}\\[6pt]
 ={}& 5\cdot 2^{n-1}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{[(1-z)^n + 3\cdot (2z)^n]^3[(1-z)^{2n} + (4z(1-z))^n + (2z)^{2n}]}}\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 5\cdot 2^{n-1}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{[(1-z)^4 + 3\cdot (2z)^4]^3[(1-z)^{8} + (4z(1-z))^4 + (2z)^{8}]}}\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 5\cdot 2^{n-1} \tag{3}
\end{align*}
where in (1) we use
$$x^ny^n \le \sqrt{x^ny^n}(x^n + y^n)/2, $$
and
$$z^{2n} = z^n\cdot z^n \le z^n (x^n + y^n)/2,$$
and
$$x^n + y^n \le (x + y)^n = (1 - z)^n,$$
and in (2) we use $xy \le (x + y)^2/4$,
and in (3) we use
$$[(1-z)^4 + 3\cdot (2z)^4]^3[(1-z)^{8} + (4z(1-z))^4 + (2z)^{8}] \le 1.$$
(The proof is not difficult.)
We are done.
